# Keras layer channel-wise multiplication of scalar and graph plotting

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to multiply scalar values to each channel in a tensor:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.ones([2,3,3,4])
w = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], dtype=tf.float32)
tf.multiply(t,w)
```

yields

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3, 3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[1., 2., 3., 4.],
         [1., 2., 3., 4.],
         [1., 2., 3., 4.]],
         ...
```

which is correct.

Now I am trying to wrap that operation inside a `keras.layers.Layer`, whereby `w` is a learnable parameter. I also try to plot my model using `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(m)`. I encounter several problems.

#### Method 1

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(256,), trainable=True)

    def call(self, x):
        return x * self.w
```

I plot this model using

```
mm = MyModel()

x = Input(shape=(64, 64, 256), batch_size=10, name='Input')
m = Model(inputs=[x], outputs=mm.call(x))
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(m)
```

**Problem**: I encountered the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.math.multiply_2), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
```

**Question**: Can I savely ignore the warning and the weights are still learned? If yes, how can I suppress this warning?

#### Method 2

As suggested in the warning, I wrap the multiplication in its own subclassed layer:

```
class MyMultiply(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMultiply, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.multiply(x[0], x[1])

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(256,), trainable=True)
        self.mul = MyMultiply()

    def call(self, x):
        return self.mul([x, self.w])
```

**Problem**: This works until the model is plotted. Then I encounter the following error: `AttributeError: 'ResourceVariable' object has no attribute '_keras_history'`

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-e4cc5cc97726> in <module>()
     21 x = Input(shape=(64, 64, 256), batch_size=10, name='Input')
     22 m = Model(inputs=[x], outputs=mm.call(x))
---> 23 tf.keras.utils.plot_model(m)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/node.py in <lambda>(t)
    259     if self.is_input:
    260       return []
--> 261     inbound_layers = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t._keras_history.layer,
    262                                         self.call_args[0])
    263     return inbound_layers

AttributeError: 'ResourceVariable' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

**Question**: How do I resolve that error? Is this a bug (I submitted an issue to the tf github repo, however it was deleted immediately)?

#### Method 3

I try to use `keras.layers.Multiply` instead:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Multiply

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(256,), trainable=True)
        self.mul = Multiply()

    def call(self, x):
        return self.mul([x, self.w])
```

**Problem**: `ValueError: Can not merge tensors with different batch sizes. Got tensors with shapes : [(10, 64, 64, 256), (256,)]`

To my understanding, the ValueError occurs because the internal `_Merge` layer checks for equal batch sizes. The internal `Multiply` layer however implements the multiplication with broadcasting (which should work!):

```py
# from tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py line 316-320
def _merge_function(self, inputs):
    output = inputs[0]
    for i in range(1, len(inputs)):
      output = output * inputs[i]
    return output
```

I could use `tf.broadcast_to` and so on, however, to my understanding this would materialize the tensor and would occupy more memory which I try to avoid.

**Question**: Is there another way to make `keras.layers.Multiply` work, so ultimately the model plotting works?

Comment: In Method 2 the weights should be added to the Layer not the Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the warning in **Method 1** by creating a Keras Layer instead of a Model.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()

        self.w = self.add_weight(name='multiply_weight', shape=(256,), trainable=True)

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.multiply(x, self.w)

mul_layer = MyLayer()
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 256), batch_size=10, name='Input')
output = mul_layer(x)
m = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=output)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(m)
```

[image: Output]